# How to make if all columns are empty then an exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to optimize the sql query?
select returns empty data (columns).
How to make if all columns are empty then an exception
There is a query:

```
begin  
   select t1.status, t1.curr, t1.amount, t1.serv  
     into stat,curr,amnt,serv  
   from table1 t1  
   where t1.id = 78;   
exception when no_data_found then 
                  result := 1;  
                  stat := 'R';  
          when stat is null and curr is null and amnt is null and serv is null then  
                  result := 1;  
                  stat := 'R';   
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If all those variables are declared as `NULL` by default, then they will remain `NULL` if

- there's no row in `table1` whose `ID = 78`, so `NO_DATA_FOUND` will be raised, or
- there actually *is* such a row, but all those columns' values are `NULL`

  - this doesn't lead to an *exception*, so you'll have to raise one yourself - if you want

In both cases, variables' values will remain `NULL` which means that you could use something like this:

Sample data first:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set ver off
SQL> select * From table1;

        ID S       CURR
---------- - ----------
        22 X          2
        78
```

PL/SQL block with a custom-made exception:

```
SQL> declare
  2    result   number;
  3    l_status table1.status%type;
  4    l_curr   table1.curr%type;
  5
  6    my_exc   exception;
  7    pragma   exception_init(my_exc, -20001);
  8  begin
  9    select t.status, t.curr
 10      into l_status, l_curr
 11      from table1 t
 12      where t.id = &par_id;
 13
 14    if l_status is null and l_curr is null then
 15       raise my_exc;
 16    end if;
 17
 18    dbms_output.put_line('Everything is OK');
 19
 20  exception
 21    when no_data_found or my_exc then
 22      result := 1;
 23      l_status := 'R';
 24      dbms_output.put_line('Exception has been raised');
 25  end;
 26  /
Enter value for par_id: 22
Everything is OK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_id: 78
Exception has been raised

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_id: 55
Exception has been raised

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: 3rd option   this doesn't lead to an exception, so you'll have to raise one yourself - if you want

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to add required predicates into the query, so you will need just one common exception handler for both cases:

```sql
begin  
   select t1.status, t1.curr, t1.amount, t1.serv  
     into stat,curr,amnt,serv  
   from table1 t1  
   where t1.id = 78
   and (
        t1.status is not null 
     or t1.curr   is not null
     or t1.amount is not null
     or t1.serv   is not null
     );
exception when no_data_found then 
                  result := 1;  
                  stat := 'R';  
end;
/
```